# Sublime doesn't recognize embedded ruby tags in html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2, rubymine

For some reason my current Sublime Text 2 setup doesn't recognize embedded ruby tags in `.html.erb` files.  The `<% %>` symbols and do/end symbols should be highlighted and matched together with HTML (Rails) syntax, right?.

Does anyone have a simple explanation for this and/or an easy way to fix it?  I want it to look like it does in RubyMine.

Comment: I don't think ST has built in support for ERB syntax, but there are plenty of plugins that should do the trick.

Comment: I've tried installing several of them (e.g. BeautifyRuby, etc.) but they don't seem to do anything.

Comment: I don't do much Rails work, but I have ERB Autocomplete installed and it seems to work.

Comment: Do I need to adjust my user settings file?

Comment: I installed ERB Autocomplete and adjusted my user settings file like so:  {"auto_complete_selector" : "text.html.erb, source - comment, meta.tag - punctuation.definition.tag.begin", "color_scheme": "Packages/RailsCasts Colour Scheme/RailsCastsColorScheme.tmTheme", "ignored_packages": ["Vintage"]}  Still doesn't seem change anything though.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Do any Sublime packages work for you? Does it recognize the file as an ERB file (check the bottom right corner)?

Comment: Yeah it says ERB on the bottom right.  I think that it might be recognizing the ruby syntax, but I'm not sure.  It displays <% %> tags in white, while if/end/do/class/yield keywords are all displayed in orange.  I'm using the "Railscast" color scheme.